# Can't get values submitted using thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new with thymeleaf and I am having a doubt about how to retrieve a field from html (using Thymeleaf) to Java (Spring Boot). Follow the code and the error that I am having:

HTML (part with issue)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<title>Entity Migration</title>

<!-- CSS  -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    media="screen,projection" />
<link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    media="screen,projection" />


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Entity
                Migration</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Entity Migration</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i
                class="material-icons">Logout</i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
        <div class="container">
            <br> <br>
            <div class="row center">
                <h5 class="header col s12 light">Fill the form below to
                    generate your XML:</h5>
            </div>
            <br> <br>

        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="col s12" action="#" th:action="@{/prepareData}" th:object="${entity}" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <input type="number" id="release" name="release" placeholder="Release" 
                    class="validate" th:value="*{release}"/>

            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
                <input placeholder="Version" id="version" name="version" type="number"
                    class="validate" th:value="*{version}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate XML" id="generate"
                class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange" />
        </div>
    </form>
        <!--  Scripts-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').material_select();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Java (Spring Boot Controller)

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/prepareData")
  public String prepareData(@ModelAttribute(value="entity") EntityMigration entity) {
    TemplatePrepare tP = new TemplatePrepare();
    tP.prepareMainTemplate(entity);
    return "results";
```

EntityMigration (Java Model)

```
public class EntityMigration {

    private String release;
    private String version;

    public String getRelease() {
        return release;
    }
    public void setRelease(String release) {
        this.release = release;
    }
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Error

```
    2017-11-16 14:01:02.445 ERROR 26932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "mainForm": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/mainForm.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/mainForm.html]")
```

(...)

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "release" (template: "mainForm" - line 55, col 23)
```

(...)

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'release' cannot be found on null
```

(...)

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the html part coming from mainForm.htm? The form balise doesn't end. In the html you posted.

Comment: That handler method returns `"results"`, which means it'll show `templates/results.html`, not `templates/mainForm.html`.

Comment: @XavierBouclet Yes, it's. I just post the relevant part. Please, let me know if it's necessary to include all of it.

Comment: @Andreas That method will get the values from the mainForm.html (I already have another route for it) and after it's ok, open the results.html part.

Comment: Can you post the entire mainForm.html? At first glance, it seems Thymeleaf can't parse the HTML, nothing related with the java code. So I'm guessing you have some invalid HTML.

Comment: can you try <input type="number" id="release" placeholder="Release" class="validate" th:value="${entity.release}">
 I didn't test the code sorry.

Comment: Hi @yvanavermaet, it's updated with the full file.

Comment: Hi @ak38, unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing html exception was caused by forgetting to close input tags. Please replace:

```
<input type="number" id="release" placeholder="Release" class="validate" th:value="*{release}">
<input placeholder="Version" id="version" type="number" class="validate">
```

with:

```
<input type="number" id="release" placeholder="Release" class="validate" th:value="*{release}"/>
<input placeholder="Version" id="version" type="number" class="validate"/>
```

Latter error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'release' cannot be found on null
```

is caused by trying to access 'release' on 'entity' -> entity is null so Thymeleaf can't render it.

You must addAttribute 'entity' to model in order to render it.
In order to avoid SpelEvaluationException you can check for null in controller:

```
if (entityManager!= null) {
    model.addAttribute("entity", entityManager);
} else {
    model.addAttribute("entity", new EntityManager());
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pavle Eftimovski, I included the close tags, but it didn't resolve the problem. For now, I am using just on release to test if the value will be sent. Is it mandatory to set in all fields to make it work?

Comment: Can you please be more specific and attach error that you are receiving now. Tnx

Comment: Hi @Pavle Eftimovski, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: @JuliaBel Latest error 
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'release' cannot be found on null
 means that your entity object in th:object="${entity} is null.
Please check/send me method in your controller class that adds entity object to your model variable.

Comment: you are right. I took off the entity object and the page is working wonderfully. 
This object wasn't set with any value, so, it should only be used when I set something on the page. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Thank you so much, @Pavle Eftimovsky.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to use the name attribute in the input, and to close you input, so replace:

```html
<input placeholder="Version" id="version" type="number" class="validate">
        <input type="number" id="release" placeholder="Release" class="validate" th:value="*{release}">
```

with:

```html
<input placeholder="Version" id="version" name="version" type="number" class="validate" />
        <input type="number" id="release" name="release" placeholder="Release" class="validate" th:value="*{release}" />
```

or you can use the

Comment: Hi @amir elhajjam, unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem.